# Do I need to do anything when a company I own stocks in is moving from OTC to NYSE?

Tags: stocks, investing, nyse

I own some stocks of a company. I read that they are moving from OTC to NYSE. One article I read said that the OTC stock will "be no more". What happens to my stocks? Will they automatically turn into NYSE stocks? Do I need to sell the OTC stocks and then buy NYSE stocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When switching exchanges, the company and the stock remain the same.

If the ticker symbol changes, your brokerage firm will provide the new symbol on your trading platform/statement and may contact you as well.